# Proc For SSRS Report shows a high number of executions ExecutionLog shows low Execution count for Report

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssrs

So, I am using SolarWinds DPA tool to monitor DB activity and obv do things based on that information.

I found a stored procedure that is being used for a SSRS report that has a high number of executions (in the millions) where as the ExecutionLog from the ReportServer shows that the report itslef is utilized maybe 30 or 40 times a day.

Now, I am not that knowledgeable on SSRS, so maybe its a thing I am not aware of?

Can anyone provide any information that might be useful in my endeavor to figure out why there is such a high execution count? Most of googling turns up unrelated results, so maybe I dont know what exactly i should be googling?

In the mean time, I am going to run a trace on the server and see what that shows me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you fetching the execution count for the proc? Have you correlated the dates in ExecutionLog with the proc statistics? Is the proc called once per report execution, or multiple times?

Comment: I found out the stored procedure being used for this report has several cursors in it (for which im not certain they need to be used?) and the actual proc executions per day are less than 40. So, Im inclined to think maybe its the cursors but im not sure yet.

Comment: Forgive me for asking but is there an actual problem with symptoms? Or are you trying to troubleshoot phantom large numbers that look bad in a monitoring tool but don't necessarily reflect an actual problem?

Comment: @Libertheme I think that is exactly what is happening. Sorry at the time I didnt know exactly what was going on or what that actually meant. I think its an issue where the reporting tool is racking up counts of executions of the cursor's query. Sorry I havent came back to this topic yet - i keep getting pulled in different directions O_o